# maven release:prepare version character error

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin, prepare

I'm trying to get the maven release plugin working, integrating with Perforce. I finally got somewhere yesterday and managed to run:

```
mvn release:prepare
```

and was asked to specify a lot of versions and new working snapshots. I specified the version "0.1" (without the quotes) as the release version for all the sub-projects, and set the working snapshot to "1.0-SNAPSHOT" (same as before), as I was just testing the plugin and the integration with Perforce, rather than actually trying to build a release. However, after entering the information I got the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.1:prepare (default-cli) on project myproject: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.1:prepare failed: The data "0.1" is not legal for a JDOM character content: 0x1b is not a legal XML character. -> [Help 1]

(I'm not 100% sure that was the exact error I got)

But now, everytime I run `mvn release:prepare`, I get that same error (definitely the one above), without getting a chance to re-supply versions or working snapshot names.

Is the version "0.1" not valid, or have I somehow managed to enter an escape character ("0x1b") in one of the values, or is there something wrong somewhere else?

I also can't find where the values I entered have gone. How would I be able to set them again, or start the prepare from scratch inputing new values?

Thank you in advance to anyone having a look at this.

EDIT:

I've found an answer to the latter part, that is, how to reset the values. If I run

```
mvn release:prepare -Dresume=false
```

I get to enter the values again.

(And as @tom has mentioned in an answer already, I can run `mvn release:rollback` to get rid of the ones that are there. However, this doesn't seem to work probably because the prepare failed.)

This time I entered the default values, but I've noticed that my problems are a lot deeper than that, and I probably haven't set up the Perforce integration properly. I get this INFO output:

> No password found, proceeding without it.

Even though I've set it up as:

```
<server>
  <id>ip-of-perforce-server</id>
  <username>my-perforce-username</username>
  <password>***************</password>
</server>
```

in my settings.xml. I've only seen it setup in examples in the pom of the project, but it was mentioned that you can do it in the settings.xml and that seems to be the only thing that makes sense (as the pom would normally be *in* the SCM). I can avoid getting this message if I specify the username and password as env vars (-Dusername=xxx, etc).

But I also get the error:

> CommandLineException Exit code: 1 - Client 'PCNAME' unknown - use 'client' command to create it.

where PCNAME is the windows name of my desktop. I tried running:

```
p4 client
```

and that opens a file with the contents:

```
Client: PCNAME
Owner:  my-perforce-username
Host:   PCNAME
```

so why is it saying it's unknown/needs creating?

To answer myself, I just noticed that after running `p4 client` it said `Client PCNAME saved.` which I guess is why it was displayed :P So following the instruction in the error message was all I had to do.

Now I only have to problems:

If I run in cygwin I get the error `Path 'D:\Server\pom.xml' is not under client's root '/cygdrive/d/Server'` which I guess has something to do with conflicts between unix and windows paths.

Apart from that I don't get any errors before after entering the versions where I get the following:

```
java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
    at java.io.Win32FileSystem.canonicalize(Win32FileSystem.java:396)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:559)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.perforce.command.edit.PerforceEditCommand.createCommandLine(PerforceEditCommand.java:109)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.perforce.command.edit.PerforceEditCommand.executeEditCommand(PerforceEditCommand.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.command.edit.AbstractEditCommand.executeCommand(AbstractEditCommand.java:40)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.perforce.PerforceScmProvider.edit(PerforceScmProvider.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.AbstractScmProvider.edit(AbstractScmProvider.java:560)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRewritePomsPhase.writePom(AbstractRewritePomsPhase.java:631)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRewritePomsPhase.transformProject(AbstractRewritePomsPhase.java:231)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRewritePomsPhase.transform(AbstractRewritePomsPhase.java:125)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRewritePomsPhase.execute(AbstractRewritePomsPhase.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:234)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.prepareRelease(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:291)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.execute(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:247)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)                            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)                                        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
[ERROR] CommandLineException Exit code: 1 - Usage: add/edit/delete [-c changelist#] [ -d -f -k -n -v ] [-t type] files...
Missing/wrong number of arguments.

Command line was:p4 -d D:\Server -p perforce-ip-and-port -u my-username -P my-password edit
org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineException: Exit code: 1 - Usage: add/edit/delete [-c changelist#] [ -d -f -k -n -v ] [-t type] files...
Missing/wrong number of arguments.
```

and the final Maven Build Failure error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.1:prepare (default-cli) on project project-name: Error writing POM: D:\Server\pom.xml (Access is denied) -> [Help 1]
```

(Note that this also happens when running the command on command line, where the error about the pom not being in the client's view does *not* appear)

Which seems to be my last remaining problem... getting there :)

Comment: You can delete `release.properties` and retry - this file stores the values you have entered.

Comment: I ran `mvn release:prepare -Dusername=MyName -Dpassword=*****` and this way I didn't get the "No password found" message, but still the "Client X unknown" ERROR...

Comment: Just noticed that the "PCNAME" value above is also the "Host" value if I go to `Connection > Edit Current Workspace...` in p4v and look under the `Advanced` tab. Should this really be the IP (or host name) of the perforce server. It seems (from changing this) that this is the host from where the client is allowed to connect to the workspace from? Would that possibly be related to the error?

Comment: I've created a new question for the problems I encountered after solving the initial ones here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999403/maven-releaseprepare-ioexception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0.1 is definitely a legal version. The values you entered have gone into files at the same level as your `pom.xml` file (Can't remember the name because they disappear after `mvn release:perform`). To erase them you can use `mvn release:rollback`

Also when using multi-module projects be sure to use the 'autoVersionSubModules' flag:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.plugin.release.version}</version>
    <configuration>
            <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This will also change the version of your modules.

EDIT: this answer only answers the part about the maven release plugin.  Not the other parts of the question.  The questioner has decided to ask new questions concerning the other parts of the question.

Comment: I've added some updates to my question following your answer (and figuring out how to get rid of the broken input). As a side note, it worked OK when I later used "0.1" again, so I must have managed to get an escape character in there the first time.

Comment: Since this one has pretty much answered my original question, I'm going to accept it and ask a new question with my current problem (this one has grown a bit too big anyway) :)

Comment: You are right about that.  One question per 'thread' keeps it easy for other people to identify with their problem and maybe find a solution.  Thanks.

Comment: By the way, I found out what the problem was and "fixed" it. See the other question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999403/maven-releaseprepare-ioexception) if you want to read about it.