# maven release:prepare IOException

Tags: maven, ioexception, maven-release-plugin, prepare

I'm trying to get maven's release plugin working with Perforce. When I run:

```
mvn release:prepare -Dusername=PerforceUser -Dpassword=PerforcePassword
```

I get this output (with some IPs/username/passwords removed):

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:                                                                                         [INFO]
[INFO] root-project
[INFO] project1
[INFO] project2
[INFO] project3
[INFO] project4
[INFO] project5
[INFO] project6
[INFO] project7
[INFO] project8
[INFO] project9
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building root-project 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.3.1:prepare (default-cli) @ root-project ---
[INFO] Verifying that there are no local modifications...
[INFO]   ignoring changes on: **\release.properties, **\pom.xml.next, **\pom.xml.releaseBackup, **\pom.xml.backup, **\pom.xml.bran
ch, **\pom.xml.tag
[ERROR] Path 'D:\Server\pom.xml' is not under client's root '/cygdrive/d/Server'.
[INFO] Checking dependencies and plugins for snapshots ...
What is the release version for "root-project"? (com.company:root-project) 1.0: :
What is SCM release tag or label for "root-project"? (com.company:root-project) root-project-1.0: :
What is the new development version for "root-project"? (com.company:root-project) 1.1-SNAPSHOT: :
[INFO] Transforming 'root-project'...
[INFO]   Updating project8 to 1.0
[INFO]   Updating project4 to 1.0
[INFO]   Updating project1 to 1.0
[INFO]   Updating project3 to 1.0
[INFO]   Updating project6 to 1.0
[INFO]   Updating project7 to 1.0
[INFO]   Updating project9 to 1.0
[INFO]   Updating project5 to 1.0
java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
    at java.io.Win32FileSystem.canonicalize(Win32FileSystem.java:396)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:559)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.perforce.command.edit.PerforceEditCommand.createCommandLine(PerforceEditCommand.java:109)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.perforce.command.edit.PerforceEditCommand.executeEditCommand(PerforceEditCommand.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.command.edit.AbstractEditCommand.executeCommand(AbstractEditCommand.java:40)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.perforce.PerforceScmProvider.edit(PerforceScmProvider.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.AbstractScmProvider.edit(AbstractScmProvider.java:560)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRewritePomsPhase.writePom(AbstractRewritePomsPhase.java:631)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRewritePomsPhase.transformProject(AbstractRewritePomsPhase.java:231)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRewritePomsPhase.transform(AbstractRewritePomsPhase.java:125)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRewritePomsPhase.execute(AbstractRewritePomsPhase.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:234)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.prepareRelease(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:291)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.execute(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:247)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)                            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
[ERROR] CommandLineException Exit code: 1 - Usage: add/edit/delete [-c changelist#] [ -d -f -k -n -v ] [-t type] files...
Missing/wrong number of arguments.

Command line was:p4 -d D:\Server -p *The-IP-of-Perforce* -u *PerforceUser* -P *PerforcePassword* edit
org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineException: Exit code: 1 - Usage: add/edit/delete [-c changelist#] [ -d -f -k -n -v ] [-t type] files...
Missing/wrong number of arguments.

Command line was:p4 -d D:\Server -p *The-IP-of-Perforce* -u *PerforceUser* -P *PerforcePassword* edit
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.perforce.command.edit.PerforceEditCommand.executeEditCommand(PerforceEditCommand.java:71)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.command.edit.AbstractEditCommand.executeCommand(AbstractEditCommand.java:40)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.perforce.PerforceScmProvider.edit(PerforceScmProvider.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.AbstractScmProvider.edit(AbstractScmProvider.java:560)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRewritePomsPhase.writePom(AbstractRewritePomsPhase.java:631)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRewritePomsPhase.transformProject(AbstractRewritePomsPhase.java:231)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRewritePomsPhase.transform(AbstractRewritePomsPhase.java:125)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRewritePomsPhase.execute(AbstractRewritePomsPhase.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:234)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.prepareRelease(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:291)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.execute(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:247)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] root-project ........................................ FAILURE [22.348s]
[INFO] project1 ............................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] project2 ............................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] project3 ............................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] project4 ............................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] project5 ............................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] project6 ............................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] project7 ............................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] project8 ............................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] project9 ............................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 22.967s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jun 12 15:41:53 BST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/154M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.1:prepare (default-cli) on project root-project: Error writing POM: D:\Server\pom.xml (Access is denied) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

This happens both when I run it in cygwin and when I run it in a normal native Windows command prompt.

Before I got this far in the setup, I was sure it managed to write the versions to the pom at least once, but now it doesn't.

Comment: When running from windows console, it fails with the same exception?

Comment: Yes :) Also, if I run a "dryRun" (-DdryRun=true) it works (I guess because it doesn't try to write to the pom).

Comment: It looks like the plugin is having trouble with your pc's particular configuration, you are running from a mapped drive maybe or something like that. Try submitting a bug report [here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE)

Comment: Just noticed that I'm _also_ getting the Path error in the command prompt, which I guess suggests I've got a cygwin-formatted path somewhere I shouldn't... @donsenior: Yes, I believe my D drive is mapped to my C drive, though I can't figure out how to tell :P

Comment: I finally figured out why I got the Path error; I had originally run `p4 client` from cygwin, which had created the client "PCNAME" with root `/cygdrive/d/server/`. I now managed to delete the client `p4 -d PCNAME` and create it in the cmd prompt `p4 client` and now I don't get that error in the cmd prompt (but this one in cygwin: `[ERROR] D:\Server\pom.xml - file(s) not in client view.`) The rest of the errors are still the same, though.

Comment: I'm confused. Now I'm getting the new ERROR in both cygwin and on the command prompt...

Comment: @donsenior Actually, after looking closer and running `subst` (which only lists my 'I' drive), I think the D drive is just a separate partition on the same hard drive as C, so I guess that should work exactly the same as if it was a separate drive, right? I've submitted a bug report.

Comment: Partitions should be transparent for the user and applications, regardless the partition is on the same drive or not. Can you see partition D the same way you see partition C on your PC explorer (or "My PC")? Maybe some cygwin configuration is causing the problem... I wish you good luck with that bug report, and sorry for my English!

Comment: I've tried creating a new workspace/client on my C: drive and ran `mvn release:prepare -Dusername -Dpassword -Dclient=new_client` in the command prompt without doing anything in cygwin, and I get the same latter errors (but not the one regarding "X - file() not in client view"), so I guess that part at least _has_ got something to do with cygwin.

Comment: Regarding my D drive, in explorer it's got this icon: http://usdn.nodevice.com/static/exts_icons/001/vhdx.png which is the same as my F (physical) and I (mapped) drives. The C drive has the one with a darker front and a windows icon (as it has the OS on it). Don't think any of that means too much...

Comment: I see, p4 command is failing cause the plugin is failing in getting the pom.xml path (so the command runs without that value and fail), so the question is why the plugin fails getting the pom path :( I'm right? Could you run de mvn command with the -X switch? Maybe it gives us some good info...

Comment: I think it must be able to read the pom, as it gets the previous version that it asks to increment. Also, if I run the command with -DdryRun=true it completes OK (after downloading lots of stuff, and running the tests). So I think it's only the bit where it needs to checkout/edit the pom that's failing... I can try running the command with -X. Should I add the output as a comment, in the question or as an external link (e.g. to my blog)?

Comment: I think this command `p4 -d D:\Server -p *The-IP-of-Perforce* -u *PerforceUser* -P *PerforcePassword* edit` lacks the file parameter (after the `edit`) and that's why it fails. The -dryRun options states "don't checkin or tag anything in the scm repository... scm operations (only listed on the console)". Could the "only listed on the console" means it does not actually run the command and that's why it works? Put the output where ever you feel comfortable, maybe editing your original question?

Comment: I've attached the full output to be bug report, so you should be able to access it here: http://jira.codehaus.org/secure/attachment/60243/mvn_release_output_x.txt

Comment: Are you sure the pom.xml is not a read-only file don't you? :P Does the process have R/W access to D:\Server? this message is very direct: `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Server\pom.xml (Access is denied)`

Comment: Perforce makes all the files read-only until you check them out (or manually change them to be writeable). I think the edit command that is missing the pom.xml should make the file writeable, so I think the "Access is denied" message is caused by that one failing. If I look at the file now, it's read-only. But if I run the command adding the "pom.xml" to the end of it, it checks out the file in perforce and it becomes writeable...

Comment: Actually, I think I've figured out why it's failing to get the file. Above I say that the command works, but it only works if I manually specify the client/workspace to use. So when I earlier in the project got an error message telling me the client didn't exist and I needed to run `p4 client` to create it, I should instead have specified the existing one. Now I just need to find out how to set the client/workspace in an env var (-D) or something...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12543/discussion-between-donsenior-and-svend-hansen)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [maven scm provider for perforce source code](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-providers/maven-scm-provider-perforce/xref/org/apache/maven/scm/provider/perforce/command/edit/PerforceEditCommand.html) I can see that on line 93 it creates the basic p4 command line

```
Commandline command = PerforceScmProvider.createP4Command( repo, workingDirectory );
```

then on line 95 it adds the edit

```
command.createArg().setValue( "edit" );
```

and *then* inside the try-catch it adds the files. But line 109

String canfile = file.getCanonicalPath();

is throwing the IOException seen above causing the stacktrace to be printed and this is why the file(s) don't get added and the execution of the p4 command fails (which in turn causes the "Access is denied" because it's failing to checkout the file (which is therefore read only).

EDIT:

The reason it throws the IOException is that when it creates the file on line 103:

```
File file = new File( workingDirectory, fs.get( i ).getPath() );
```

the `fs.get( i ).getPath()` returns an absolute path, so file ends up looking like

```
D:\Server\D:\Server\pom.xml (in my case)
```

and this is obviously broken.

I've changed the line (and a similar line in [PerforceCheckInCommand.java](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-providers/maven-scm-provider-perforce/xref/org/apache/maven/scm/provider/perforce/command/checkin/PerforceCheckInCommand.html) locally to:

```
File file = null;
if(fs.get( i ).isAbsolute()) file = new File( fs.get( i ).getPath() );
else file = new File( workingDirectory, fs.get( i ).getPath() );
```

and reinstalled the plugin and now it all works. So the problem is a bug in the plugin causing my particular setup to fail. I've submitted a bug report, so hopefully no one else will experience this, but if they do, download the plugin src, make those two changes and re-install it (mvn install), and it should work.

Comment: I insist, I think that is a vicious circle, you need to run the edit command so that perforce make the file writable, but the plugin needs the file to be writable so it can create the edit command... Have you tried manually making the file writable? Has the file the right permissions? Try making the workspace in the shared folder...

Comment: However it still doesn't explain why I'm getting the exact same error even with the exact same line number of cannonical name io call. This line number contains only curly brace in provider version 1.8 so I have to be using old version although I have explicitely defined the version of maven-scm-plugin.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Even though I got a different error, this pointed me in the right direction of updating to version 1.8.1 of the scm plugin suite.

Comment: well done Svend for finding the problem, for fixing it, and for sharing! I have a similar issue with the release plugin for TFS ... :-(